# How to setup MTLTexture and MTLBuffers for Metal Performance Shaders Find Keypoints

Tags: objective-c, metal, metalkit, metal-performance-shaders

## Problem

I'm trying out the performance shaders for the first time and encountered a runtime problem. The `MTLTexture` that `MTKTextureLoader` returns seems to be uncompatible with Metal Performance Shaders' `MPSImageFindKeypoints` encoder.

The only hint so far that I found is from @warrenm's sample code on MPS that specifies `MTKTextureLoaderOptions` just like I did. I did not find any other mentions in the docs.

Any help is highly appreciated.

## Error

```
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/MetalImage/MetalImage-121.0.2/MPSImage/Filters/MPSKeypoint.mm:166: failed assertion `Source 0x282ce8fc0 texture type (80) is unsupported
```

where 0x282ce8fc0 is the `MTLTexture` from the texture loader.
As far as I could see there is no MTLTexture type 80, the enum ranges up to 8 or so (not hex).

## Code

```
CGFloat w = CGImageGetWidth(_image);
CGFloat h = CGImageGetHeight(_image);
id<MTLDevice> device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice();
id<MTLCommandQueue> commandQueue = [device newCommandQueue];

NSDictionary* textureOptions = @{ MTKTextureLoaderOptionSRGB: [[NSNumber alloc] initWithBool:NO] };
id<MTLTexture> texture = [[[MTKTextureLoader alloc] initWithDevice:device] newTextureWithCGImage:_image
                                                                                         options:textureOptions
                                                                                           error:nil];
id<MTLBuffer> keypointDataBuffer;
id<MTLBuffer> keypointCountBuffer;

MTLRegion region = MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, w, h);

id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = [commandQueue commandBuffer];
MPSImageKeypointRangeInfo rangeInfo = {100,0.5};
MPSImageFindKeypoints* imageFindKeypoints = [[MPSImageFindKeypoints alloc] initWithDevice:device
                                                                                     info:&rangeInfo];
[imageFindKeypoints encodeToCommandBuffer:commandBuffer
                            sourceTexture:texture
                                  regions:&region
                          numberOfRegions:1
                      keypointCountBuffer:keypointCountBuffer
                keypointCountBufferOffset:0
                       keypointDataBuffer:keypointDataBuffer
                 keypointDataBufferOffset:0];

[commandBuffer commit];

NSLog(keypointCountBuffer);
NSLog(keypointDataBuffer);
```

## Edit

After converting my image to the correct pixel format I am now initialising the buffers like so:

```
id<MTLBuffer> keypointDataBuffer = [device newBufferWithLength:maxKeypoints*(sizeof(MPSImageKeypointData)) options:MTLResourceOptionCPUCacheModeDefault];
id<MTLBuffer> keypointCountBuffer = [device newBufferWithLength:sizeof(int) options:MTLResourceOptionCPUCacheModeDefault];
```

There is no error anymore. But how can I reading the contents now?

`((MPSImageKeypointData*)[keypointDataBuffer contents])[0].keypointCoordinate` returns (0,0) for all indexes. Also I don't know how to read the `keypointsCountBuffer`. The buffer contents converted to an int value show a higher value than the defined maxKeypoints. I don't see where the docs say what kind of format the count buffer has.

Comment: Are you really not setting `keypointDataBuffer` or `keypointCountBuffer` before encoding the command? Maybe not relevant, but could break things internally such that the assertion is a "sympathetic" error and misleading. Also, those `NSLog()` calls can't work. They need a format string.

Comment: @KenThomases Yes currently I don't know any better than to assume that both buffers will be initialized by MPS upon calling encode or when committing the commandBuffer, since the docs don't specify how these buffers should be set and I would not know how large the buffer needs to be. I guess I could set the `keypointDataBuffer` to the maximum keypoints count that I define in the `rangeInfo` and try again. Indeed I was expecting maybe getting errors for those logs but I just did not look up how to log MTLBuffers yet.

Comment: I just saw that I overlooked that the docs state that `MPSImageFindKeypoints` needs a texture with `MTLPixelFormatR8Unorm`. So After correcting the images pixel format I indeed run into the error that keypointsDataBuffer may not be null

Comment: In (Objective-)C (as opposed to C++), a method can't modify a variable passed as an argument unless you pass its *address*. So, there was no chance that the method would create buffers and set your variables to point to them, given how they're passed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally the code is running and just for completeness sake I thought I should post the whole code as an answer

### code

```
id<MTLDevice> device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice();
id<MTLCommandQueue> commandQueue = [device newCommandQueue];

// init textures
NSDictionary* textureOptions = @{ MTKTextureLoaderOptionSRGB: [[NSNumber alloc] initWithBool:NO] };
id<MTLTexture> texture = [[[MTKTextureLoader alloc] initWithDevice:device] newTextureWithCGImage:_lopoImage
                                                                                         options:textureOptions
                                                                                           error:nil];
MTLTextureDescriptor *descriptor = [MTLTextureDescriptor texture2DDescriptorWithPixelFormat:(MTLPixelFormatR8Unorm) width:w height:h mipmapped:NO];
descriptor.usage = (MTLTextureUsageShaderRead | MTLTextureUsageShaderWrite);
id<MTLTexture> unormTexture = [device newTextureWithDescriptor:descriptor];

// init arrays and buffers for keypoint finder
int maxKeypoints = w*h;
id<MTLBuffer> keypointDataBuffer = [device newBufferWithLength:sizeof(MPSImageKeypointData)*maxKeypoints options:MTLResourceOptionCPUCacheModeWriteCombined];
id<MTLBuffer> keypointCountBuffer = [device newBufferWithLength:sizeof(int) options:MTLResourceOptionCPUCacheModeWriteCombined];

MTLRegion region = MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, w, h);

// init colorspace converter
CGColorSpaceRef srcColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceSRGB);
CGColorSpaceRef dstColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceLinearGray);

CGColorConversionInfoRef conversionInfo = CGColorConversionInfoCreate(srcColorSpace, dstColorSpace);
MPSImageConversion *conversion = [[MPSImageConversion alloc] initWithDevice:device
                                  srcAlpha:(MPSAlphaTypeAlphaIsOne)
                                 destAlpha:(MPSAlphaTypeNonPremultiplied)
                           backgroundColor:nil
                            conversionInfo:conversionInfo];

// init keypoint finder
MPSImageKeypointRangeInfo rangeInfo = {maxKeypoints,0.75};
MPSImageFindKeypoints* imageFindKeypoints = [[MPSImageFindKeypoints alloc] initWithDevice:device
                                                                                     info:&rangeInfo];

// encode command buffer
id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = [commandQueue commandBuffer];
[conversion encodeToCommandBuffer:commandBuffer sourceTexture:texture destinationTexture:unormTexture];
[imageFindKeypoints encodeToCommandBuffer:commandBuffer
                            sourceTexture:unormTexture
                                  regions:&region
                          numberOfRegions:1
                      keypointCountBuffer:keypointCountBuffer
                keypointCountBufferOffset:0
                       keypointDataBuffer:keypointDataBuffer
                 keypointDataBufferOffset:0];

// run command buffer
[commandBuffer commit];
[commandBuffer waitUntilCompleted];

// read keypoints
int count = ((int*)[keypointCountBuffer contents])[0];
MPSImageKeypointData* keypointDataArray = ((MPSImageKeypointData*)[keypointDataBuffer contents]);
for (int i = 0 ; i<count;i++) {
    simd_ushort2 coordinate = keypointDataArray[i].keypointCoordinate;
    NSLog(@"color:%f | at:(%u,%u)", keypointDataArray[i].keypointColorValue, coordinate[0], coordinate[1] );
}
```

I guess there should be a more clever way to allocate the keypoint buffers with `[device newBufferWithBytesNoCopy]` so then you would not need to copy the contents back into your allocated arrays. It just didn't figure out to correctly align the buffer.

Also I should mention that I guess usually you will have a grayscale texture after any kind of feature detection so that the image converting part will not be necessary.